# Approximation of a compactly supported function by Gaussians

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, approximation-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function whose support is a closed interval, e.g. $\text{supp}(f)=[a,b]$. Then $f$ can be approximated (e.g. in $L^2$) by a linear combination of Gaussian densities, i.e.
$$
f(x)
\approx 
G_n(x)
:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,n} g(x;\mu_{i,n},\sigma_{i,n}^2),
\quad
a_{i,n}\in\mathbb{R},
\quad
g(x;\mu,\sigma^2) 
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac1{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}.
$$

Suppose that for sufficiently large $n$, a **best approximation** to $f$ exists in some norm (again, e.g. $L^2$, but it doesn't really matter), i.e.
$$
\Vert f-G_n^*\Vert
\le \inf\big\{\Vert f-G_n\Vert : a_{i,n}\in\mathbb{R},\, \mu_{i,n}\in\mathbb{R},\, \sigma_{i,n}^2>0 \big\}
$$

and furthermore $G_n^*\to f$.

I'd like to show that as long as $n$ is sufficiently large, then $\mu_{i,n}^*\in [a,b]$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. In other words, if a best approximation is arbitrarily close to $f$, it can't do something stupid like use a Gaussian component whose mass is mostly concentrated off of $\text{supp}(f)$.

The difficulty as I see it is that the weights $a_i$ can be arbitrarily close to 0, so there exist (arbitrarily) good approximators $G_n$ with "rogue" components (i.e. $\mu_i\not\in\text{supp}(f)$), but whose weight $a_i$ is very small. the challenge is showing somehow that "best" approximators avoid this kind of pathology.

**Edit:** Changed the assumptions so that the support of $f$ is necessarily an interval---this may not be true for arbitrary compact sets.

Comment: Do you allow $G_n$ to be an arbitrary linear combination of Gaussians, i.e. the parameters under the inf are all $a$s, $\mu$s and $\sigma$s?

Comment: @Dirk: Yes. (Although, does it matter? Even if you restrict all parameters to lie in some compact set, I still don't see a way out.)

Comment: What about taking $f$ as a truncated (and suitably smoothed) Gaussian where $\mu$ is far away from $K$? If $n$ is equal 1 you should get this Gaussian back (if the smoothing is small enough).

Comment: @Dirk: If I understand your counterexample correctly, you are simply defining the parameter space such that any approximation will be bad. I have updated the question to reflect the requirement that $G_n^*\to f$.

Comment: Are weights constrained to be positive ?

Comment: @PiyushGrover: Not necessarily, but I am interested in the special case $a_i\ge 0$ as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect the conjecture to be true ? I believe you may need to put sparsity (like an L1 norm) and/or positivity constrains on weights to get what you want.

Comment: If you draw $f$ and ask someone to "draw" their best approximation to $f$ from this family, my guess is they would never include a random bump outside the support of $f$. More technically, if my conjecture is false, it says that even though the distance between $G_n^*$ and $f$ is arbitrarily small, adding a bump $g_k$ off the support somehow improves the approximation (note that you can always remove the bump and still remain in the same class by choosing $a_k=0$). This seems very strange to me. If a counterexample exists, I'd love to see my intuition invalidated!

Comment: I am not sure that your conjecture is true. Take for instance the function $f(x)=g(x;-0.3, 1)+g(x;1.3,1)$ along $[0,1]$ and 0 otherwise. Then for $n\geq 2$ the best approximation (which is norm 0 away from $f$!) obviously has weights outside of $[0,1]$. $${}$$ If the $G_n$ are constrained to have supports within $[a,b]$ they can still approach a measurable function in a norm sense.

Comment: @enthdegree What is the interval $[a,b]$ in your example? Is it not the case that your choice of $f(x)$ has $\text{supp}(f)=(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: @enthdegree "obviously has weights outside of [0,1]" This is not at all obvious to me. I am also not sure why your approximation is norm zero away from $f$. (To be clear, the error is being measured globally on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and not just on $[a,b]$.)

Comment: Suppose $\mu_i \notin [a,b]$. Can we show that it is always better to replace $(a_i,\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ with $$\left(a_i\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\right)-a_i\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\right), E[X], Var[X]\right)$$ where $X$ is the normal distribution $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ truncated to $[a,b]$?

Comment: I do not have access to Mathematica at the moment, so I cannot check that numerically, but I would not be surprised if something like [$G_3(x) := 4 e^{-x^2} - e^{-(x-1)^2} - e^{-(x+1)^2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B4Exp%5B-x%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x-1)%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x%2B1)%5E2%5D,%7Bx,-4,4%7D%5D) was the best fit to, say, $f(x) := G_3(x) \mathbb{1}_{[-3/4,3/4]}(x)$. Informally: one may need Gaussians with negative weights and means outside $[a,b]$ to cancel out the "excess" of other Gaussians with positive weights and means inside $[a,b]$. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, what smooth cutoff function do you use to define $f$? Since we are concerned with whether any $\mu$'s are inside $[a,b]$, the behavior near the boundary may make a difference.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, $\|f-G_3\|_2^2=0.6$, but $\|f-\pi e^{-2x^2}\|_2^2=0.4$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B4Exp%5B-x%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x-1)%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x%2B1)%5E2%5D,Pi+Exp%5B-2x%5E2%5D%7D%5D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5B(4Exp%5B-x%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x-1)%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x%2B1)%5E2%5D)%5E2,%7Bx,3%2F4,3%7D%5D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5B(4Exp%5B-x%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x-1)%5E2%5D-Exp%5B-(x%2B1)%5E2%5D-Pi+Exp%5B-2x%5E2%5D)%5E2,%7Bx,-3%2F4,3%2F4%7D%5D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5B(Pi+Exp%5B-2x%5E2%5D)%5E2,%7Bx,3%2F4,3%7D%5D

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Note that I am interested in the case $n\to\infty$ and $G_n\to f$, so counterexamples for any finite $n$ won't disprove the conjecture.

Comment: @MattF. Nice! Your idea is more or less what I've been trying, although I haven't tried your specific example (I will think about it). My basic intuition is that if $\mu_i\notin[a,b]$ and $\Vert G_n-f\Vert$ is sufficiently small, then moving $\mu_i$ back "into" [a,b] should result in a better approximation.

Comment: Is this essentially asking for a theorem that kernel density estimation is well-behaved under the assumed norm?

Comment: @student: This is a good thought, but unfortunately not. There are several reasons why, the simplest being that the KDE is a random object (depending the samples drawn from $f$), whereas this problem is purely deterministic. Moreover, if we draw samples from $f$ and form the associated KDE, it is easy to show that the resulting mixture model will always have $\mu_i\in[a,b]$. It is easy to construct good approximations with $\mu_i\in[a,b]\,\forall i$ and also good approximations with $\mu_i\notin[a,b]\,\exists i$, however, this question is very specifically about the _best approximation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:** Let $f\geq 0$. We consider the following easier problem :$$ \|f-G_n^*\|_{L^1}\leq \inf \{\|f-G_n\|_{L^1}:a_{i,n}\geq 0, \mu_{i,n}\in \mathbb{R}, \sigma_{i,n}>0 \}. $$
Since $f\geq 0$, we have $G_n^*\rightarrow f $. In this case, for any $n$ we have $\mu_{i,n}^*\in [a,b]$. Intuitively, otherwise more than half of the mass of a gaussian would be outside $[a,b]$ and gives a strictly positive contribution to the norm.

Detailed proof:
We have
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} |G_n - f|dt=\int_a^b |G_n - f|dt + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left(\int_{-\infty}^a g_i(t)+ \int^{-\infty}_b g_i(t)dt\right)$$where $g_i(t)=g(t;\mu_i,\sigma_i)$. Let $G_n^*$ a best approximation and suppose that there exists $\mu_i^*<a$ (resp $>b$). For $s\in [0,1]$, define $$G_n(s)=G_n^* - (1-s)a_i g_i. $$  $G_n(s)$ is the same as $G_n^*(s)$ with $a_i$ replaced by $s a_i^*$.
Therefore
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |G_n(s) - f|dt & = \int_\mathbb{R} |G_n^* -(1-s)a_ig_i- f|dt\\
&\leq \int_a^b \Big\{|G_n^* - f|+(1-s)|a_i g_i|\Big\}dt + \int_{t\notin [a,b]} |G_n^*-(1-s)a_i g_i| \\
&= \int_a^b \Big\{|G_n^* - f|+(1-s)|a_i g_i|\Big\}dt + \int_{t\notin [a,b]} G_n^*-(1-s)a_i g_i \\
&= \int_a^b |G_n^* - f|dt+\int_{t\notin [a,b]} G_n^* dt  \\ &\quad+(1-s)a_i \left(\int_a^b g_idt-\int_{t\notin[a,b]} g_i(t)dt\right)\\
\end{align}$$
But because $\int_{-\infty}^a g_i(t)dt> \frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_a^b g_i(t)dt< \frac{1}{2}$ the last term is stictly negative and we have 
$$\|G_n(s)-f\|=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |G_n(s) - f|dt < \int_{\mathbb{R}} |G_n^* - f|dt = \|G_n^* - f\|$$
for all $s\in (0,1)$ which is in contradiction to the minimisation of $G_n^*$. $\square$

**Case 2:** We don't make any assumption in $f$, the norm $\|.\|$ or the positivity of $a_i$. Here I don't have a rigorous proof but I argue that your claim is not true. I try to construct the following counter example:  Let $$f(t)=1_{[-1,1]}(t)g(t)$$ and  $$h(t)=f(t)-g(t)$$ where $g(t)=g(0,1,t)$.

I make the following natural generalisation of your claim: if $\text{supp}(f) = (-\infty,a]$ or $\text{supp}(f) = \mathbb{R}-[a,b]$ and $f$ decay to 0 fast enough at $\pm \infty$ then your claim is also true for $f$.

We note $F_n^*$ be the best approximation of $f$ and $H_n^*$ the best approximation of $h$. Now remark that 
$$\|h - H_{n+1}^*\| \leq \| h - F_n^* +g\|= \|f-F_n^*\|$$ and 
$$\|f - F_{n+1}^*\| \leq \| f - H_n^* -g\|= \|h-H_n^*\|$$
So 
$$\|f - F_{n+2}^*\| \leq  \|h-H_{n+1}^*\| \leq \|f - F_{n}^*\|$$
Therefore $H_{n+2}^* + g $ is also a very good approximation of $f$ and is least better than $F_n^*$. 
But if both yours claim and the natural generalisation I proposed were true then as $n\rightarrow \infty$ all the gaussian of $H_n^*$ should be centered in $\mathbb{R}-[-1,1]$ and all the gaussiaan of $F_n^*$ should be centered in $[-1,1]$.
But this seems to me very hard to believe that $H_n^*-g$ and $F_n^*$ are so different one to another and yet gives almost as good approximation of $f$.

Comment: This is more or less the strategy I have been trying, but I don't quite follow your line of reasoning (e.g. where do you use $\int_{-\infty}^ag_i(t)dt>1/2$?).

Comment: Also, your argument does not appear to use the fact that $G_n\to f$ -- as @Dirk pointed out in the comments it is easy to construct counterexamples otherwise, even when $G_n$ is a best approximation. These counterexamples are somewhat pathological, however, so maybe I just missed some steps in your argument.

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^a < 1/2$ then $\int_a^b - \int _{-\infty}^a-\int_b^\infty < 0$. And if $f$ is positive the best approximation $G_n$ with $a_i \geq 0$  converge to $f$.

Comment: @JohnA What about the given example, $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(x) \, g(x; \frac{a+b}{2}, \sigma)$? I think it is easy to imagine that this will have $\mu_i$ spread out over all of $\mathbb{R}$, and should even be easy to verify numerically? Even as $n \to \infty$, I find it hard to convince myself that at any point the Gaussian at the centre should be replaced.

Comment: @student The case $a_i\ge 0$ discussed in this answer seems more interesting, but the given example certainly sheds doubt on the case $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Nonetheless, it is still not clear that with sufficiently many Gaussians you couldn't approximate the interior of $[a,b]$ better than the tails in the complement $[a,b]^c$. Also, I am not sure how easy this would be to verify numerically?