# Best approximation of a compactly supported density by a single Gaussian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control, approximation-theory

*Note: This is a follow-up question inspired by a [previous (more difficult) question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325885/approximation-of-a-compactly-supported-function-by-gaussians) I asked on MathOverflow.*

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a (sufficiently regular, e.g. smooth) probability density supported on the (compact) interval $[a,b]$. Let $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ be some norm (e.g. $L^2$, total variation). What is the best approximation to $f$ by a single, univariate Gaussian? In other words, solve
$$
\text{argmin}_{m\in\mathbb{R},v^2\ge 0}\Vert f-g_{m,v^2}\Vert
$$

where $g_{m,v^2}$ is the Gaussian PDF with mean $m$ and variance $v^2$. As I mention above, this question is related to a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325885/approximation-of-a-compactly-supported-function-by-gaussians); I realized while trying to solve that problem that even the simple case of a single Gaussian seems nontrivial.

**Hint:** I have verified numerically, for both $L^2$ and TV norm, that **the answer is not $m=\mathbb{E}_{X\sim f} X$ or $v^2=\text{var}_{X\sim f} (X)$**.

**Note:** The details of which norm (or even metric) or regularity assumptions are made are not important here. I am mostly curious to see if this computation can be carried out for any "reasonable" distance and regularity. In fact, even the case of minimizing over $m$ alone (holding $v^2$ fixed) appears difficult. Note that for the KL-divergence (which is neither a norm nor a metric), this can be solved in closed form quite easily.

Comment: The natural thing to try, for say $L^2$, is to differentiate (under the integral sign) with respect to $m$ and $v$, set them equal to zero, and try to solve.  Does anything useful happen when you do that?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I have tried that and the resulting integral equation is daunting.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't expect to get a closed-form solution to the equations (say for $L^2$), but numerical methods should work reasonably well.

Comment: Among the other possibilities for norms to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance#Examples

Comment: @MattF Absolutely. The reason I focused the question on norms (and $L^2$ in particular) is that I suspect this should be easier to solve in a Hilbert space. Any probability metric (e.g. Wasserstein, Hellinger) would be of interest as well.

Answer (score 2):

(i) You can try to minimize the squared Hellinger distance 
$$H(m,v)^2:=\frac12\,\int(\sqrt f-\sqrt{g_{m,v^2}})^2
=1-\int \sqrt f \sqrt{g_{m,v^2}}, 
$$
which amounts to the maximization of the comparatively simple expression 
$$J(m,v):=\int \sqrt{f(x)}\frac1{\sqrt v}\,\exp\Big\{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{4v^2}\Big\}dx
$$
in $m,v$.

In particular, if $f$ is log concave, then the integrand in the latter integral is log concave in $(m,x)$. So, by the Prékopa--Leindler theorem (see e.g. [Corollary 3.5](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123676900045)), $J(m,v)$ is log concave in $m$ and hence will usually have a unique maximum in $m$. If, moreover, $f$ is symmetric about the midpoint $(a+b)/2$ of the interval $[a,b]$, then the maximum of $J(m,v)$ in $m$ is at $m=(a+b)/2$, and then it remains to maximize $J((a+b)/2,v)$ in $v>0$, which should usually be easy to do.

E.g., if $f$ is the density of the beta distribution Beta$(p,p)$ with parameters $\alpha=p$ and $\beta=p$ with $p\ge1$, then $J(m,v)$ is log concave in $m$ and its maximum in $m$ is at $m=1/2$. Here is a graph of the ratio of the maximizer of $J(1/2,v)$ in $v>0$ to the true standard deviation of the Beta$(p,p)$ distribution as the function of $p\ge1$:

[image]

We see that this ratio is pretty close to $1$ already for $p=1$.

(ii) Alternatively, you can try to minimize 
$$\int(\ln f-\ln{g_{m,v^2}})^2d\mu
=\int\Big(\ln f(x)+\ln\sqrt{2\pi}+\ln v+\frac{(x-m)^2}{2v^2}\Big)^2\,\mu(dx)   
$$
for some measure $\mu$. Expanding the latter integrand and then integrating term-wise, we see that, for a given measure $\mu$, this reduces to the minimization in $v>0$ and $m$ of a linear combination of the form 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{15}c_j w_j(m,v),
$$
where, for each $j$, $c_j$ is a known real number and $w_j(m,v)$ is a rather simple elementary function of $m,v$.

Comment: Why the downvote? This approach seems to lead to a tractable case. Also, is the normalization in your maximization expression correct?

Comment: @lcv : Thank you for your comment. I have now corrected that normalization factor.

Comment: For i), would you suggest integration over $[a,b]$ or over $\mathbb{R}$?  For ii), the only sensible bounds are $[a,b]$.

Comment: @MattF. : All the integrals are over $\mathbb R$. Note that in (ii) the integral is with respect to a measure $\mu$, to be appropriately chosen.

Comment: I have added some details.